# Symbol "$MKRORIGIN" used but not found in libraries

Tags: proteus

I'm using Proteus Professional v8.11 SPO and whenever I'm trying to open a proteus file this error pops up.

Symbol "$MKRORIGIN" used but not found in libraries

Although the the file opens finally (after pressing OK three times), simulation does not execute properly. (Simulation is executing in other computers)

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5enZP.png)

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Try running ISIS.EXE with administrator rights.